# How do I make the rest of the page fade to black once my div loads and fade out once the div is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've been piecing together code and tweeking it to eventually come together with this. The code itself is fairly simple and basically just saying that once someone visits the page for the first time then drop a cookie and no longer display it for the visitor when he visits the page, well for 365 days. My only issue is that once the div loads and loads out, I can't figure out how to fade in and fade out the background, I can only fade the div itself. I've tried wrapping it in a overlay div but I think I'm approaching it all wrong.
The code looks a bit much on here so I've attached a jsfiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/newbieturd/F29uv/

** Note: Once you run the fiddle once, you will have to clear your cookie. The DIV only appears once

CSS:

```
#welcome {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:34px 18px 18px 18px;
  height:120px;
  width:300px;
  background:Salmon;
  color:#f9f9f9;
  border-radius:6px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin:-60px 0 0 -150px;
  font:300 normal 1.4em/1.2 'Signika', sans-serif;
  display:none;
}
#close {
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background:url('http://www.omagdigital.com/images/articles/WebArticle-CloseButton.png') no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  top:2px;
  right:2px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
(function(factory){if(typeof define==='function'&&define.amd){define(['jquery'],factory);}else{factory(jQuery);}}(function($){var pluses=/\+/g;function raw(s){return s;}function decoded(s){return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses,' '));}function converted(s){if(s.indexOf('"')===0){s=s.slice(1,-1).replace(/\\"/g,'"').replace(/\\\\/g,'\\');}try{return config.json?JSON.parse(s):s;}catch(er){}}var config=$.cookie=function(key,value,options){if(value!==undefined){options=$.extend({},config.defaults,options);if(typeof options.expires==='number'){var days=options.expires,t=options.expires=new Date();t.setDate(t.getDate()+days);}value=config.json?JSON.stringify(value):String(value);return(document.cookie=[config.raw?key:encodeURIComponent(key),'=',config.raw?value:encodeURIComponent(value),options.expires?'; expires='+options.expires.toUTCString():'',options.path?'; path='+options.path:'',options.domain?'; domain='+options.domain:'',options.secure?'; secure':''].join(''));}var decode=config.raw?raw:decoded;var cookies=document.cookie.split('; ');var result=key?undefined:{};for(var i=0,l=cookies.length;i<l;i++){var parts=cookies[i].split('=');var name=decode(parts.shift());var cookie=decode(parts.join('='));if(key&&key===name){result=converted(cookie);break;}if(!key){result[name]=converted(cookie);}}return result;};config.defaults={};$.removeCookie=function(key,options){if($.cookie(key)!==undefined){$.cookie(key,'',$.extend({},options,{expires:-1}));return true;}return false;};}));

function setCookie() {
  $.cookie("visited", "true", { expires: 365 });
}

if ($.cookie('visited') != 'true') {
  $('#welcome').show(1800);
  setCookie();
} else {
  $('#welcome').remove();
}

$('#close').click(function() {
  $('#welcome').hide(1800);
});

// $.cookie("visited", null);
});//]]>  

</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="welcome">
  <span id="close"></span>
  Interstitial Message. You will only see this message once every 365 days.
</div>
  <p> Hello World. </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I gave the popup a parent container that will serve as the overlay.

`HTML`:

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div id="welcome">
      <span id="close"></span>
      This is the only time you will see this message :)
    </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    z-index: 99;
}
```

`jQuery`:

```
if ($.cookie('visited') != 'true') {
  $('#welcome, .overlay').show(100); // If the condiditon is true then show overlay
  setCookie();
} else {
  $('#welcome').remove();
}

$('#close').click(function() {
  $('#welcome').hide(100); // Can also be added to this jQuery selector but the animation was odd
    $('.overlay').fadeOut(100); // Fades out on click
});
```

Finally the fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F29uv/17/)

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't completely understanding the "overlay". Thanks again for the help!

Comment: If there is more you don't understand about it then just ask and I can explain how it works! If not best of luck on your project mate.

Answer (score 0):

Give your #welcome div a z-index (11 for example) and add css to give your document body full height and width:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

You're going to add a glass pane div to the body and it needs a height and width to fill the body of the page which, in your current example, has no height or width set

And then add a background div with a color of your choosing and a z-index less than your #welcome div such as:

```
<div id="glass_pane" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 10; position: absolute: top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: #000;"></div>
```

Ans then fade it in or out, remove it when you like, change the transparency